# Attach function/condition jQuery Dialog autoOpen Parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I need to check for a value on page load that will determine whether or not the dialog should autoOpen.  I imagined that this would work similar to the way close is handled, but that's not the case.

```
$(".x_dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: function(){ret();}
});

 function ret() {return false;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was wrong.

After the page has loaded, check for the conditions and then call

```
$("#x_dialog").dialog("open");
```

If appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

autoOpen can only accept `true` or `false`. Calculate the value before you initialize the dialog

```
var autoOpen = (1 === 2);

$(".x_dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: autoOpen
});
```

alternatively you can set it to the returnvalue of a function, but the function must return a boolean-like value.

```
$(".x_dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: ret() // note the `()`, this means the function gets executed immediately
});
```

Comment: ok, it's not as simple as described. Say I have 2 modals on the page, but I only want 1 to open automatically? I should probably edit my question--aha, I see your edit(s) testing

Comment: The thing is, my edit is essentially exactly the same as my original as far as the logic goes.

Comment: I am going to see if I can pass a parameter, hopefully $(this) works

Comment: Basically, as long as what ends up beign returned immediately to that option is a boolean value, it will work. It can't be function() { ...} unless it is executed immediately, such as (function(){...})()